How to set database credentials from application
I am getting database credentials from Azure Vault and I want to set database credentials from application. After getting database credentials from Azure vault i am trying to set it using following in ServletContextListener class of method contextInitialized. I have also tried to set it before InitialContext lookup method.
System.setProperty("db.username", "username");
System.setProperty("db.password", "password");

I am using wildfly-9.0.1.Final server. In standalone.xml file, i have set the following property.
<security>
  <user-name>${db.username}</user-name>
  <password>${db.password}</password>
</security>

Can anyone tell me how can we set database credentials from application? Any help will be appreciated.

What is the framework of your App?

I am trying to do it with servlet.
